# How to add .patch file code to usb_modeswitch and add support for 3G USB modem?

Tags: networking, usb, usb-modem, modem, 3g

so I want to switch over to ubuntu from windows but unfortunately after doing some research I found out that my 3G USB modem doesn't work well with GNU/Linux in that you have to configure your own support for the device. My device is a D-Link DWR-510, on the official manual it states that it supports GNU/Linux although upon further investigation I've found that this is not true.

Through another forum's question I found someone who coded a usb_modeswitch DB / .patch file which is supposed to add support for my device, although because I have absolutely no idea what I'm doing, and this is my only source of internet (3rd world country ftw) I have to know how to get it working before I switch over, this is the source of the code: http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1127

here is the code in case you don't actually want to go to the website:

```
# D-Link DWR-510

TargetVendor=  0x2001
TargetProductList="7e12"

MessageContent="5553424308407086000000000000061b000000020000000000000000000000"
```

thank you for actually clicking on this question and reading this far

Comment: As far I can understand Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has usb-modeswitch and has rule for `2001:a805`, it does not contain `MessageContent`, but only `StandardEject=1`. Does `2001:a805` represent your USB modem in-before-switch state? Have you tested your modem on 16.04?

Comment: No I haven't tested it, but I can't test it before switching from windows to ubuntu because this 3G modem is my only source of internet connection (as I stated in the OP) and if for some reason it doesn't work I won't have any way to access the internet

It's good to hear that it already contains support; and I'm not sure if 2001:a805 represents my USB modem in-before-switch state because I don't know how to identify my USB modem in-before-switch state, how do I found that out?

Comment: In Ubuntu `lsusb` is your friend, in Windows you can use [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) to determine USB VID and PID of yours modem.

Comment: Hey there thanks for replying, my VID is 2001 and my PID is 7e12, if 2001:a805 means V&PID then I assume usb-modeswitch doesn't support my rule, what does this mean?

Comment: `2001:a805` may be before switch, I do not know how to detect it on Windows. According to [this page](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/3G_/_3.5G) it seems that before switch modem is really  `2001:a805` and after is `2001:7e12`. Modern Ubuntu 18.04 (alpha) has `StandardEject=1` too. So I hope that you do not need to patch usb-modeswitch rules.

Comment: Me too hahaha; but before I install ubuntu and go completely dark, can you tell me how to use the usb-modeswitch patch? I've been googling this entire time and I feel so idiotic unable to find an answer for myself

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the solution will be as following:

```
# 1. change directory to /tmp
cd /tmp

# 2. create "patch"-file
cat <<EOF > 2001\:a805
# D-Link DWR-510

TargetVendor=0x2001
TargetProduct=0x7e12

MessageContent="5553424308407086000000000000061b000000020000000000000000000000"
EOF

# 3. copy existing rules-archive to /tmp
cp /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz /tmp

# 4. unpack it
gunzip configPack.tar.gz

# 5. remove existing rule from archive
tar --delete --verbose --file configPack.tar 2001\:a805

# 6. add new rule file
tar --update --verbose --file configPack.tar 2001\:a805

# 7. pack archive
gzip configPack.tar

# 8. copy updated archive to its normal location
sudo cp configPack.tar.gz /usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz
```

Hope this helps.

You can always revert `/usr/share/usb_modeswitch/configPack.tar.gz` archive to version from repository with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall usb-modeswitch-data
```

Comment: thank you very much, I'll get to installing ubuntu now and try this, if it doesn't work then well...I hope I can find some other method to come back and ask more questions lmao

Comment: You can install in dual-boot mode, or install on USB-flash as starting point.

Comment: Alright, thanks again, I'll get a USB and boot it up from there and see if it works without the steps, and if not I'll try using the steps and report if it fixed the problem, you must really like doing this hahaha thanks again

Comment: Just finished testing and it seemed to register the device, it shows the name of the network, GPRS roaming (even though I'm not roaming) and what appears to be a signal strength however it's greyed out, once I contacted my ISP and added the APN settings and tried to connect through that it would disconnect me after a few seconds of trying to connect, here's a screenshot of what it looks like if that matters (sorry for fade): https://prnt.sc/hw50f4

I noticed that if I switch to router mode on my modem I can connect via WiFi but the internet doesn't work

Comment: It seems that you are testing it from LiveCD/LiveUSB. It may exclude serious system updates. If you have free 16Gb USB-flash, you can install Ubuntu on it and test again. I have no D-Link DWR-510 modem, but my ZTE MF192+ works normally.

Comment: Yes the usb I was testing it on is 32GB, I will install ubuntu on it and test again

Comment: So after going to the store and buying another drive and installing ubuntu on the other 32GB drive it still doesn't work and does the same thing...I'm starting to think now, should I reeaally be considering switching over to ubuntu if I can't fix this myself? oh well

got any other ideas or have we hit the wall here?

Comment: Other solutions: 1. use cheapest mobile phone as Wi-Fi hotspot and connect Ubuntu to its Wi-Fi.  2. if you computer is fast enough you may want to install Ubuntu into VirtualBox, it will use network connection of host (Windows) system. 3. insert you USB modem to the 3G/Wi-Fi router with USB port. 4. insert SIM card from modem to 3G/Wi-Fi router which is compatible with your operator.

Comment: Well, thanks for trying N0rbert, I guess that is the only solution,though can't afford to do that atm but I'll eventually get around to buying a new 4G hotspot in like, a few months lmao, so hopefully then...I'm coming for you ubuntu

fml

thanks again N0r